# Trying to update multiple rows when one attribute present

Tags: ms-access

In ms access I am trying to update a single field in multiple rows when any of those rows has a specific value in another field.

Ex:

```
Heading1 | Heading 2 | Heading 3
Apple    | cow       | no
Apple    | monkey    | no
Apple    | cow       | yes
Orange   | horse     | no
Orange   | horse     | no
Grape    | pig       | no
Grape    | pig       | yes
```

In any instance where `Heading3` is `yes` I want all `Heading3` items set to `yes`.  The result would be:

```
Heading1 | Heading 2 | Heading 3
Apple    | cow       | yes
Apple    | monkey    | yes
Apple    | cow       | yes
Orange   | horse     | no
Orange   | horse     | no
Grape    | pig       | yes
Grape    | pig       | yes
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I've proposed an edit to add some formatting to make your table easier to read. In addition, I think you should clarify: in any instance where `Heading3 = yes` *for a specific value in `Heading1`*, all row entries *where `Heading1` have that same value* should have `Heading3` set to `yes`, correct?

Answer (score 0):

So Heading2 has no relevance?
You do this by joining the table with itself:

```
UPDATE myTable AS t1 INNER JOIN myTable t2 
ON t1.Heading1 = t2.Heading1
SET t1.Heading3 = 'yes'
WHERE t2.Heading3 = 'yes'
```

If I understand the question correctly, that is.